# convert an array of hexadecimal octets to a string variable in bash

Tags: bash

Is there a "better" way to convert an array of hexadecimal to a string variable in shell other than the following?

Maybe via variable substitution?

```bash
# the following is a hex representation of the string "filename.txt"
a=(66 69 6c 65 6e 61 6d 65 2e 74 78 74);
var="";
for i in ${a[@]}; do \
        var+=$(echo -n -e "\x$i");
done;
echo $var;
# -> filename.txt
```

I'm searching for a plain bash solution without using perl, python nor other script languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
$ a=(66 69 6c 65 6e 61 6d 65 2e 74 78 74)
$ printf -v var '%b' "${a[@]/#/\\x}"
$ echo "$var"
filename.txt
$
```

See [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf) and [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for further information.